# Run MATLAB runtime code against files on hadoop

Tags: matlab, hadoop, hdfs

Here's the situation: We are doing a POC for a customer that analyses medical images for radio-therapy using MATLAB. The've automated everything with a nice framework based on micro-services. That way everything is automated from the moment the file comes in on a specific (windows) file-location until everything is processed and analysed.
The customer has asked us to do a POC with their software to see if it runs faster on HADOOP. The idea we have at this time is to run everything on windows, but keep the files stored on Hadoop. But that means that the MATLAB runtime has to connect to HDFS. Our Hadoop System is actually Microsoft HDInsight, as part of a Microsoft APS.

The have compiled there own runtime, but we also have the source-code of the runtime. We cannot install anyhting on the Windows servers where Hadoop is installed. We do have a server that is able to connect to the Hadoop servers  and were we have installed the Matlab runtime.

How do we proceed with this? 
Is it possible to put the files that need to be analyzed on Hadoop en execute the MATLAB runtime from a windows machine?
Are my thoughts on this matter too simple? Or do we need to write map/redcue code that needs to be integrated in the MATLAB runtime?

Comment: The files are just on HDFS? Not Hive, for example? Does it have to be MATLAB code? I would think you'd get more usage out of Spark, for example

Comment: Indeed, the files are just on HDFS, No Hive or what so ever. And it has to be MATLAB code. The scientists that write the MATLAB code only know MATLAB. Seems that it is common use in the medical world to use MATLAB for these sort of analysis

Comment: Well... If data were in Hive tables, I'd suggest you use JDBC / ODBC so you could run SQL over it. Have you tried to use this?  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mapreduce.html